# Unable to connect to Kafka running on windows desktop from a docker container running on the same machine

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am trying to connect to kafka running on windows desktop from the docker container which is also running on the same desktop.

For the connection string, I am using my FQDN and the port.

i.e <HOSTNAME.domain.com>:9092

Regards
Amit

Comment: Did you try `localhost:9092` or `127.0.0.1:9092`?

Comment: yes, that didn't work because from the process running inside the container localhost is the is self.

Comment: i also tried with the hostname and that too didn't worked :(

Comment: Try this: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Comment: Did you map ports with your host when you launched your container ?